# Getting Backbone to log errors

Tags: javascript, marionette

I'm using Backbone Marionette and in most cases they seem to swallow any JS exceptions that occur (e.g. non-existent objects, incorrect variable names, operations on empty arrays), without logging anything to the console (in Chrome).

This is hugely frustrating and means I have to resort to console.log hundreds of times to try and isolate the line that is causing the error.

Any way of getting Backbone to output errors?

Comment: Have you tried adding the "use strict"; at the top of your JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no built in facilities for backbone logging. there are however some plugins that might give you more insight into whats happening,

take a look at [Backbone Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/backbone-debugger/bhljhndlimiafopmmhjlgfpnnchjjbhd?hl=en). It adds a new tab to your chrome dev tools that gives insight into what backbone is doing under the hood.